# How can I make intellij work with git hooks that use a hashbang?

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have a number of git hooks that are implemented using `node`. In order to do that, I've added a hashbang to each that looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
```

This works absolutely fine on the command line, but when one of these git hooks triggers through some action performed in IntelliJ (e.g. a post-checkout hook when you switch branches from within IntelliJ) I get the following error:

```
/usr/bin/env: ‘node’: No such file or directory
```

Is there anything I can do to stop these errors occurring in IntelliJ as they can be quite disruptive and make my git hooks ineffective? I've tried to look for configuration options for the git plugin, but nothing seems to make sense for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be caused by the `PATH` environment variable being different within IntelliJ than on the terminal and `node` simply isn't accessible to it. Knowing that, there are few ways to fix it.

- Run IntelliJ from the command line; I found this unsatisfactory as I'd no doubt forget and launch it from the dash and not notice until a hook failed.
- Add the directory for `node` to the PATH using `env` in the desktop file (this might be gnome specific); this was a bit convoluted and desktop files can get overwritten by updates anyway, so I gave up on it.
- Provide a symlink to node from a directory that *will* be on the PATH; e.g. I created a symlink `/usr/bin/node`.

There might be other options too, but hopefully this might help someone else running in to a similar issue. I encountered this issue because I was using `nvm` to manage node versions and so `node` isn't on the path until an `nvm use <version>` command has been executed. I set a default node version in `.zshrc`, but of course, that doesn't apply to IntelliJ.